# android - how to set and get value from spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to set and get value to a spinner  for item dynamically ?

any ideas ?

I just need help with the Spinner behavior right now, the rest should be quite easy.

Comment: checkout here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160518/how-to-add-items-to-the-spinner-dynamically-in-android

Comment: I want every item has a value !!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177674/add-spinner-with-click-of-a-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: this is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973536/set-value-for-spinner-with-custom-adapter-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
spinnerAdapter.add("value");
spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setSelection(0);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

1. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787809/get-spinner-selected-items-text)
2. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160518/how-to-add-items-to-the-spinner-dynamically-in-android)
3. [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151699/set-text-on-spinner)

Answer (score 0):

**XML file:**

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Java file:**

public class SpinnerExample extends Activity {

```
private String[] arraySpinner;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.arraySpinner = new String[] {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    };
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

// To get value from spenner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(newAdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()   {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos,  long id) {
          Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
      }
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      }
});
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will help you.

```
Spinner mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

If you want to add the elements dynamically, you can by doing this:

```
myAdapter.add("newelement");
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinn = findViewById(R.id.socialmedia_spinner_adsocmeda);
            ArrayList<String> fam = new ArrayList<>();
            fam.add("INSTAGRAM");
            fam.add("FACEBOOK");
            fam.add("GOODWALL");
            fam.add("TWITTER");
            fam.add("YOUTUBE");
            fam.add("LINKEDIN");
            fam.add("SNAPCHAT");

            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String> (ProfileActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fam.toArray(new String[0]));
            spinn.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

That's a way we can add data to spinner.